# Bing custom search apis returning only limited results from one location and full result from different location

Tags: bing-api, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to use Bing Custom Search's API for documents from Cognitive Services. The strange thing is that when I run it from India, it gives me more than a thousand results, but when I run it from a US server, it returns only 25 (sometimes 50 results). Here is the sample code for that:

```cs
var totalCount = 0;
var filetypes = new List<string> { "pdf", "docx", "doc" };
foreach (var filetype in filetypes)
{
    var searchTerm = "microsoft%20.net%20resume+filetype%3a" + filetype;
    Console.WriteLine("Searching for : " + filetype);

    for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        var nextCount = 0;
        var url = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bingcustomsearch/v7.0/search?" +
                  "q=" + searchTerm +
                  "&customconfig=" + customConfigId +
                  "&count=25" + "&offset=" + ((i * 25) + nextCount);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);
            var httpResponseMessage = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
            var responseContent = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            BingCustomSearchResponse response =
                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BingCustomSearchResponse>(responseContent);

            if (response.webPages == null || response.webPages.value.Length <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("response.webPages is null ");
                break;
            }

            foreach (var webPage in response.webPages.value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("name: " + webPage.name);
                Console.WriteLine("url: " + webPage.url);
                Console.WriteLine("displayUrl: " + webPage.displayUrl);
                Console.WriteLine("snippet: " + webPage.snippet);
                Console.WriteLine("dateLastCrawled: " + webPage.dateLastCrawled);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            totalCount = totalCount + response.webPages.value.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

The subscription key I am using is a trial key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the reason of this behavior. Actually it had nothing to do with region/country/market. 
After looking into the response i got this message.
"Rate limit is exceeded. Try again in 1 seconds"
It means for after each call in the loop i have to wait for 1 second to give next call. Now need to know is this limit for trial subscription or this is kept for all calls to prevent DDOS attack or something.
May be from India it was working because may one iteraction is already taking one or more second.

Comment: Rate limit is applied to trial keys as well as to paid subscriptions. You can check TPS of paid subscriptions here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/search-api/web/. For custom search, it is 1 TPS for a free key. You may want to put some idle time between calls to check whether latency is the issue.

Comment: @Ronak Do you have a reference for the 1TPS on Custom Search?

Comment: Here it is: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/try/cognitive-services/?api=bing-custom-search

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can try: 1) In searchTerm, no need to use %20 and %3a, just use punctuations as you type in Bing, e.g. **var searchTerm = "microsoft.net resume filetype::"+filetype**, and 2) Enforce market by appending mkt=en-in (for India) or en-us (for US) in the query. You can do this by appending **+"&mkt=en-in"** at the end of url.

I presume for custom search you have selected domains (for ***both*** en-in and en-us markets) that return thousands of results for this query.

Comment: I tried both these options which you have mentioned about changing the searchterm and adding the market. But the behavior is same.  Even on explicitely giving the mkt parameters, there is a difference in result.From indian machine i am getting a lot of results but running from US server it gave very limited results. Is it country/region specific or something else. Because, i tried with one machine which is in EU location, then it also gave me large number of results.